# Differentiate the function into the simplest form

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My question: $y=\sin^{2}(x)$

My attempt: Is $\sin^{2}x$ the same as $(\sin(x))^2$?

By rearranging the function I came up with the following.

$$ \begin{align}
u = \sin(x), \ & y=u^2 \\
\dfrac{du}{dx}= \cos(x), \ &\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2u \\
\end{align} $$

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 2 \cos(x)$$

Is this correct? I am not sure if I'm going the correct way with the form.

Comment: Thanks jojek, where would i find the guide on how to present my equations in a better format like you have done for me?

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). As for $\sin^2(x)$, almost everytime it is $(\sin(x))^2$, but occasionally it might mean $(\sin\circ \sin)(x)$.

Comment: @John: You welcome. It's a LaTeX so please refer to: [basic tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), and [notation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). I am sure you will love it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\sin^{2}x$ is the same as $(\sin(x))^2$.

Easiest way to calculate this derivative is by using the [**Chain rule**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule). If

$$ f(x) = h(g(x))$$

then:

$$ f'(x) = h'(g(x))\cdot(g'(x)) $$

So in your case: $h(x) = x^2$ and $g(x)=\sin(x)$. That gives us:

$$\left( \sin^{2}x \right)' = 2\sin(x)\cdot (sin(x))' = 2\sin(x)\cos(x) $$

Which can be simplified by using following trigonometric property:

$$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x) $$

And in the end:

$$\left( \sin^{2}x \right)' = \sin(2x) $$

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have many more questions coming so say tuned ;)

Answer (score 1):

If we take $u = \sin(x),\; y=u^2$, then $$\dfrac{du}{dx} = \cos x\;\text{ and } \;\dfrac{dy}{du} = 2u$$

Note that you refer to $2u\,$ as $\;\dfrac{dy}{dx},\;$ which is incorrect, since we took the derivative of $y$ with respect to $u$, i.e. we computed $\dfrac{dy}{du}$.

Now what is true is that, by the chain rule, $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{du}{dx}\cdot \dfrac{dy}{du}= \cos(x)\cdot 2u = \cos(x)\cdot 2\sin(x) = 2 \sin x \cos x$$

Note that we can simplify the result using the identity $$2\sin \alpha\cos \alpha = \sin(2\alpha)$$

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct. Notice that $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx},$$ therefore $$\frac{dy}{dx} = (2u) \cdot (\cos (x)) = (2 \sin(x)) \cdot (\cos(x)) = 2 \sin (x) \cos (x) = \sin(2x).$$

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to break your even 2000 rep, but this was a nice answer :D

Comment: Thank you, Dan. It was meant to be broken. =)

Comment: Would the downvoter explain?